# player.SetDataSource media play both of tracks at the same time?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        player = new MediaPlayer ();
//Next item event
        imgNext.Click+= delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            NextTracks(mPosition);
        };
```

}

public void StartMedia(string url_string)
        {

```
        Load_Data ();
        seekBar.Progress = 0;
        seekBar.Max = 100;
        //player.Reset ();
        player.SetAudioStreamType (Stream.Music);
        player.SetDataSource(url_string);
        player.Prepare();
        player.Start ();
        imgPlayorPause.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.ic_pause_black_36dp);
        //UpdatedTimerTask ();



    }
public void NextTracks(int positon)
    {
        player = null;
        if (positon >= mListData.Count ()) {
            mPosition = 0;
        } else {
            mPosition++;

        }

        StartMedia(mListData [mPosition].stream_url + "?client_id=" + clienId);
    }
```

Media play both old track and new track at the same time. How to set it as null.

Updated add code

Comment: Updated nexttracks method

Comment: When is NextTracks method called?

Comment: Remove/comment player = null; from your NextTracks method and uncomment player.Reset from StartMedia

Comment: I have tried remove but still error

Comment: In case it still does not work, add player.Stop(); before the now uncommented player.Reset();

Comment: no error but still playing both track at the same time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110615/discussion-between-luis-beltran-and-j-joe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you declare your class, add:

```
MediaPlayer player;
```

(it means it has to be outside any method, but inside the class). Then, inside OnCreate:

`player=new MediaPlayer();`

Finally, before you call `player.Reset()`, add a call to `player.Stop();`

Comment: Can you tell us where is your original code fired? What error do you receive?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object(null exception)

Comment: all in public void startmusic(string url_string)